# react native - updating progress in the UI

Tags: react-native, setstate

I'm trying to process some data in react native javascript while showing a progress percentage in the UI.
The naive implementation is something like:

```
readData(){
  let i=0
  let len = elements.length
  for (; i < len; i++){
    this.setState({progress:i/len});
    this.process(elements[i]) // take some time
  }
}
```

This, of course, will not work, as react native batch all setstate calls and call the last one.

Anyone has an idea how it should work?

Thanks!

Comment: what does this.process(elements[i]) do ? does it return anything?

Comment: this.process, just manipulate javascript objects in this example, currently it doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update state after the progress you need to use callbacks or Promise.

**Example**

```
process(element, index, callback) {
  setTimeOut(() => {
    // some functions
    if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();
  }, (10000* index))
}

readData(){
  let i=0
  let len = elements.length
  for (; i < len; i++){
    this.process(elements[i], i, () => {
      const progress = i/len;
      this.setState({progress});
    });
  }
}
```